# How could a Focke-Wulf 190 pilot see anything at all from his cockpit?

Tags: cockpit

As one can see from the images below, the seat seems to be placed so low on the cabin, I cannot figure out how the pilot could see anything.

Can anyone explain how a [Focke-Wulf 190](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focke-Wulf_Fw_190) pilot would be able to see out of the cockpit?

[image: http://www.warbird-photos.com/airshows/2011-POFAirshow-PS-1/POF11-P1_FW-190_A8-N_0109.jpg]

[Source](http://www.warbird-photos.com/airshows/2011-POFAirshow-PS-1/POF11-P1_FW-190_A8-N_0109.jpg)

[image: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/cb/80/28/cb8028bf4688497e7a5cf5aee4583ead.jpg]

[Source](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/cb/80/28/cb8028bf4688497e7a5cf5aee4583ead.jpg)

Comment: A lot of planes have issues related to this. I remember a few years ago a WWII warbird basically ran over a small plane while taxing because of visibility issues.

Comment: Flight sims, like DCS World,  which has a version of the 190, would give you a good idea of the experience if you're interested.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks like the pilots are performing taxi-runs for show. For an actual flight, by sitting on the seat pack parachute (and/or a [cushion](https://ww2aircraft.net/forum/threads/fw-190-a-8-seat-cushion.46887/#post-1340297)) the eye level is raised as shown below:

[image]
([warbirdsnews.com](http://warbirdsnews.com/warbirds-news/fw-190-flight-gosshawk-unlimited.html))

[image]
([worldwarphotos.info](https://www.worldwarphotos.info/gallery/germany/aircrafts-2/messerschmitt-bf-109/messerschmitt-bf109-wnf-pilot/))

For how to taxi while sitting so low, it's usually down by taxiing in an S-shape or following hand signals from a [marshaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_marshalling).

---

Related:

- [How are aircraft controlled that have no forward view out of the cockpit?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7876/14897)
- [How do pilots manage to keep aircraft on centerline during taxi?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7849/14897)
- [How does a taildragger steer (taxi) differently to tricycle gear?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30757/14897)
- [Would the Gee Bee be allowed to fly today, with so little forward visibility?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33645/14897)

Comment: Long live red freehand circles!

Comment: Also, for taildraggers, the aircraft's attitude during flight is rather more level than during taxi on the ground.